# Запятая перед "как"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед "как" в выражении: "Два часа(,) как вышли из дома"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая не нужна. Здесь "как" не союзное слово, а местоименное наречие, вводит оборот со значением "в то время, когда".  Такие обороты, употребляемые для обозначения времени действия или проявления какого-либо состояния, запятой не отделяется.